# Plotting two different time series in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, time-series

I'm trying to plot two different time series on the same plot using the ggplot2 package in R.
I'm not sure why it isn't working. I believe it may be because one of the series is daily data and one is monthly.

I wrote some code for two data frames:

```
ras <- data.frame(
  date=seq(as.Date("2004-10-01"), as.Date("2015-09-02"), by = "day"),
  CONSUMERS=runif(3989,80,120)
)

umich <- data.frame(
  observation_date=seq(as.Date("2004-10-01"), as.Date("2015-02-01"), by = "month"),
  UMCSENT=runif(125,80,100)
)
```

So I want both of them on the same ggplot.
Suppose I try the following:

```
a <- ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=umich,aes(observation_date,UMCSENT)) +
  geom_line(data=ras,aes(x=date,y=CONSUMERS))
a
```

I end up with this error:

```
Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only
```

I thought I could possibly add in argument like this but I get the same error:

```
a <- ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=umich,aes(observation_date,UMCSENT)) +
  geom_line(data=ras,aes(x=date,y=CONSUMERS)) +
  scale_x_date(format = "%b-%Y")
a
```

To summarize, I'm trying to plot monthly and daily time series data on the same `ggplot`.

Comment: I am not able to replicate this problem with ggplot2 version `1.0.1`.

Comment: I am also not able to get the error for the first one using ggplot2_1.0.1.9003.  One option would be `library(gridExtra)` to arrange the plots in the same page.

Comment: In the second case, `scale_x_date(date_labels='%b-%Y')`

Comment: I'm using the most up-to-date version of ggplot2. Is there any way I can help replicate the problem? Unsure what you're asking. (Also, unfortunately I need the plots on top of one another rather than side-by-side.)

Comment: Could not replicate either. Another approach would be to combine your dataframes into one, and use grouping in ggplot.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where the problem is. Using your data, here is what I get.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ras <- data.frame(
  date=seq(as.Date("2004-10-01"), as.Date("2015-09-02"), by = "day"),
  CONSUMERS=runif(3989,80,120)
)

umich <- data.frame(
  observation_date=seq(as.Date("2004-10-01"), as.Date("2015-02-01"), by = "month"),
  UMCSENT=runif(125,80,100)
)

a <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=ras,aes(x=date,y=CONSUMERS)) +
  geom_line(data=umich,aes(observation_date,UMCSENT), color="red") +
  scale_x_date(labels=date_format('%b-%Y'))
a
```

[image]